# Google Street View Maps - Parsing url to use as street image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Situation: I'm working on a map feature for a client and I need the ability to get screenshots of a street view, and then display them as a carousel (similar to how Google does it natively). They can choose whatever locations they want in their CMS.

The only way I can think of to do this (taking into account non-tech end users) is to allow them to copy and paste the URL from a street view, and then parse it out.

For example: https://www.google.com/maps/@60.959789,-149.112111,3a,75y,104.14h,94.39t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sJmW2DmZWQ2bIcAcHlky4-w!2e0

will give you:
[image]

After tinkering around, I figure the following breakdown corresponds to [paramerters for the Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/#url_parameters)

```
60.959789 (lat)
-149.112111 (long)
3a (unknown)
75y (field of view)
104.14h (heading)
94.39t (pitch)
/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sJmW2DmZWQ2bIcAcHlky4-w!2e0 (unknown)
```

However, when I plug these into the url structure for an image, I get:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=60.959789,-149.112111&fov=75&heading=104.14&pitch=94.39

[image]

**Question**

What am I screwing up?

Can I do this a better way?

**Addendum:**
In addition, how can I get the right `pano` attribute from relevant photosphere shots? For example, how can I get a Street View Image of [this photosphere](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Acropolis+of+Athens/@37.971526,23.725783,3a,75y,7.1h,105.65t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sndpIF2nFl7EAAAQYWBSWdw!2e0!3e11!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x5c97c042f5eb0df6).

Comment: substract 90 from the pitch: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=630x279&location=60.959789,-149.112111&fov=75&heading=104.14&pitch=4.39

Comment: Yup, that does it. Do you know why theres an additional 90 degrees on the pitch? Do you know of a better way to do this?

Comment: I can't tell you, obviously they use another pitch-range. A better solution would be to implement an own interface where the users may select the desired streetview. You may read the properties of the SV via the maps-API and e.g. create a JSON-string with the values which may be copied and then pasted into your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to avoid answering my own questions, but heres what I found about parsing a URL from Google Street view for use in their Street View Image API.

```
60.959789 (lat)
-149.112111 (long)
3a (unknown)
75y (field of view)
104.14h (heading)
94.39t (pitch)
/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sJmW2DmZWQ2bIcAcHlky4-w!2e0 (unknown)
```

The `data` attribute is the interesting one. [This blog article helped me](http://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters) figure it out.

Each segment of the attribute is preceded by "!", a number from 1 - 5 (or more presumably), and a letter (m, e, etc).

For some reason the fourth element (3rd, when counting from 0) is the `pano` attribute.

Therefore, [this street view of the Acropolis](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Acropolis+of+Athens/@37.971526,23.725783,3a,73.1y,18.39h,98.42t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sndpIF2nFl7EAAAQYWBSWdw!2e0!3e11!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x5c97c042f5eb0df6) can be parsed into this url for an image:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=200x200&location=37.971822,23.726532&fov=75&heading=163.13&pitch=7.599999999999994&pano=fPhZjlaq_sAAAAQYNw-Ypw

[image]

I'm not sure what the other attributes pertain to, but I'd like to know.