# What do parameters like a, y, h and t mean in regular Google Maps URLs?

Tags: android, google-maps, url

I've come across the following problem in Google Maps URLs which I can't find a solution for anywhere:
When analyzing Google activity data, the MyActivities.json for Google Maps which results from Maps searches on an Android phone contains URLs like this:

https://www.google.com/maps/@38.2816045,-77.5006055,1198.0381738992166a,30y,217.18h,45t

When I enter this URL in a browser, the URL changes after a few seconds to:

https://www.google.com/maps/@38.2730197,-77.5089001,17z

Note that latitude/longitude have changed slightly.

I have seen the parameters a, y, h, and t before only in Streetview, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489214/google-street-view-maps-parsing-url-to-use-as-street-image).
What is their meaning in "regular" Google Maps URLs and why do they change lat/lon?

Thanks in advance for any ideas/help!